# MySQL Arabic Format Issue UTF-8 values conversion

Tags: mysql, sql, database, arabic-support

How Can I Change with PHP/MySQL Code the Arabic values to browser readable format like given below:

MySQL Query to Change Arabic Values `عبدالله السالم` to UTF-8 supported values like `Ø¹Ø¨Ø¯Ø§Ù„Ù„Ù‡ Ø§Ù„Ø³Ø§Ù„Ù…`

Is there direct function we can change for all arabic column values?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

i think UTF-8 don't support arabic values ,you have to use ISO-8859-6

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UTF-8 encoding in your pages , in the database (database , tables, columns), and before connection `SET CHARACTER SET utf8`.